# How to hide application title in WP7 application tile

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like not to show the application name in the tile of Windows Phone 7, like the Netflix or the Facebook applications do, but when I try to set it to empty (or even an empty space) Visual Studio complains that an empty title is not allowed.

Any idea of how to achieve this? The logo of my app already contains the name of the app, so having also the default title is not very nice looking.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you set the `<Title>` to a whitespace under `<Tokens><PrimaryToken>`; in `WMAppManifest.xml` you should get an empty title in the start page tile.

You shouldn' change the `Title` attribute in the  tag at the top.

Comment: Thank you. Too bad this string gets changed every time I open the Project property dialog

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project name. Go to Properties. Go to XNA Game Studio section. Where it says "Tile title:" just put a whitespace. Save everything and debug your project.

Answer (score 0):

Martin's answer didnt work for me unluckily but the thing which worked was: Double click on project properties and in the field xap file name remove underscore. It worked perfect for me.