# Hiding Tile text from Silverlight WP7 Application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I saw the post at " [How to hide application title in WP7 application tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182625/how-to-hide-application-title-in-wp7-application-tile)". However, I can't seem to find that setting in the Silverlight application. I've tried changing it in the project settings and cannot much like what was stated in the previous question.

TIA

Comment: The WMAppManifest.xml file you need to change is inside the `Properties` folder in the solution. Simple remove the value within the `Title` element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Answer seems to work.

In WMAppManifest.xaml if you remove the values in Title element, it works. Even for Mango.

```
<Tokens>
      <PrimaryToken TokenID="FishJumpToken" TaskName="_default">
        <TemplateType5>
          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.jpg</BackgroundImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          **<Title></Title>**
        </TemplateType5>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
```